# ACC API on Autodesk: propertiesUrl URI Misinterpretation in Node.js

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-construction-cloud

I've encountered an issue while using the ACC API of Autodesk Platform Service. My runtime environment is Node.js+Express.

I referred to the following API for property querying:
https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/acc/v1/reference/http/index-v2-index-jobs-batch-status-post/

Upon using it, the returned propertiesUrl and queryResultsUrl were in the following format:

```
https://bim360-nucleus-production-us-east-1-temporary-index.s3.amazonaws.com/{projectId}/index/v2/indexes/{indexId}/properties.ldjson.gz?X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Security-Token={{token_value}}-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential={{Credential_value}}/20231003/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231003T021812Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature={{Amz_Signature_Value}}
```

However, the URI is structured in such a way that authentication credentials and other details aren't being recognized correctly, preventing me from accessing the property information.

Error received:

```
Error: 400 Bad Request <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
forge-api-app | <Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>Bearer {Secret}</ArgumentValue><RequestId>{RequestId}</RequestId><HostId>{HostID}</HostId></Error>
```

Other URLs, like the manifestUrl, are returned in the format like:
https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/index/v2/projects/:projectId/indexes/:indexId/manifest

If anyone has experienced a similar issue or has found a solution, I would greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you for reading.

expample code:

```
async function getBatchStatus(header, containerID, versionDict) {
    const bashStatus_url = PROJECT_URL + containerID + "/indexes:batch-status";
    var jobsList = await post(bashStatus_url, header, JSON.stringify(versionDict));
    return jobsList;
};
```

Comment: I've edited your question to fix formatting issues, please check if the text looks right - please do not link external content as links tend to break over time, always pull as much content as possible into the question

Comment: properties and indexes are downloaded by AWS S3 signed url which highly secure your data. GET Manifest returns general information of mode indexing. They are different types of data. Could you check my sample of Node js on how to fetch properties and indexes? https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-model.properties-versions.difference/blob/main/routes/services/index-api.js

Comment: @Xiaodong Liang 
Is it challenging to use 'FilestreamGet' on the AWS S3 URLs outputted from batchStatus for 'propertiesUrl' and 'queryResultsUrl'? Additionally, is there a configuration to make batchStatus output URLs in the previous format, like 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com...'?